# I installed the environment according to the official Tensorflow tutorial, but the sample code is running incorrectly

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, anaconda

I installed the environment according to the official tutorial of Tensorflow, but the sample code is not running correctly：

1. Install anaconda
2. Install python by `conda create --name tensorflow python=3.7.4`
3. Install tensorflow by `pip install --upgrade --ignore-installed tensorflow`
4. Create a new project and select existing interpreter that i installed
5. Run the code in pycharm

Is there any step that I missed?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
hello = tf.constant("hello world")
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "E:/dp/dp_01/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(sess.run(hello))
  File "D:\Users\46173\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 956, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "D:\Users\46173\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\client\session.py", line 1105, in _run
    raise RuntimeError('The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the '
RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run().
```

Comment: I don't think this is an official TF tutorial. Check out this [beginner](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/quickstart/beginner.ipynb) tutorial from the official website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is

Tensorflow core r2.0 have enabled eager execution by default. so, without changing it
we just have to change our code

```
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
  os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
  hello = tf.constant("hello world")
  print(sess.run(hello))
```